# Hide integer in sprintf

Tags: c, printf

I'm trying to print nothing when my bool (`fps`) is set to `false`. At the moment it prints 0, because I have no other idea how I would disable the integer from displaying.

```
sprintf(drawdev, "%s%d", (fps) ? "FPS: " : "", (fps) ? framecount : 0);
```

How can I make it so the integer doesn't display, just like the "FPS: " text?

Comment: I'd put the whole `sprintf` call under a `if (fps)`.

Comment: i would use `if(fps)` instead of ternary operator

Comment: @FredLarson That's not a good option in my case since I'm going to use multiple bools in that sprintf line, using this the text will stay inline, when using multiple sprintf's for multiple bools the text will overlap eachother

Comment: have you tried using `itoa` or something similar to convert your int to a string? `sprintf(drawdev, "%s%s", (fps) ? "FPS: " : "", (fps) ? itoa(framecount, buf, 10) : "");` where buf is defined as a char array big enough to hold your integer value

Comment: @SjakM What do you mean by "multiple bools"?  Your code shows a single condition.  If that's not your real code then show your real code.  There shouldn't be any overlapping either.

Comment: @dbush What do you mean by "real code"? Notice "I'm going to use", aka I have yet to implement that.

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest way to do this is to get rid of the ternary and use an `if`:

```
if (fps) {
    sprintf(drawdev, "FPS: %d", framecount);
} else {
    sprintf(drawdev, "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
fps?sprintf(drawdev,"FPS: %d",framecount):sprintf(drawdev,"FPS:");
```

Comment: the ternary operator is not inside the format string above. it's one of the varargs to the sprintf, which is fine

Answer (score 0):

You can use the precision modifier `%.*d`, passing `0` will have no output:

```
sprintf(drawdev, "%s%.*d", (fps) ? "FPS: " : "", !!fps, (fps) ? framecount : 0);
```

Comment: Use `%.*` so you can pass precision of 0 or 1 as an argument.

Comment: @R.. thanks for the suggestion, but in this case, as far as I understand, there is no need to use * (passing 0 will disable the integer from displaying as OP requires)

Comment: Yes; you need the variable precision argument if 0 might also be a meaningful value you want to print.